# tcl return file name chosen by user

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Been banging my head against this for a day now, reminds me of learning MFC 20 odd years ago :-(

I want the user to choose a file name. Having chosen it, I want to be able to use the file name in other parts of the program. My efforts to date have ended with this:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "get user specified file name (how hard can it be?)"

labelframe .lfInput -text "user specified file name goes here"

set userChoice "userChoice is bound to this field"
# note not $userChoice in next line
entry .lfInput.ent -width 40 -textvariable userChoice
button .lfInput.but -text "Kindly press this button and choose a file.\nNot only will I write the file name\nin the the field to the left, I'll make\nit available to anyone who cares\n to press the button below."\
 -command "fileDialog .lfInput .lfInput.ent"

pack .lfInput.ent -side left -padx 10 -expand yes -fill x
pack .lfInput.but -side left -padx 10 -pady 3
pack .lfInput -fill x -padx 2c -pady 3
focus .lfInput.ent

button .b -text "Press this button to write\nuserChoice to the console\nthereby demonstrating\nthe ability to get a file\nname from the user."\
    -command "writeTheArg {$userChoice}"
pack .b


proc fileDialog {w ent} {
    set types { {"All files"       *} }

    set userFile [tk_getOpenFile -multiple false -filetypes $types -parent $w -typevariable "All files"]

    if {[string compare $userFile ""]} {
        $ent delete 0 end
        $ent insert 0 $userFile
        $ent xview end
    }

    puts "line 34: local userFile is $userFile"
}

proc writeTheArg {s} {
    puts "line 38: puts $s"
}

puts "line 41: user choice is {$userChoice}"
puts "when pressing second button, the file chosen by the user should show up here\n\
      by virtue of the textvariable option at line 9\n...\n"
```

This is overkill for it's stated purpose, anything we do here could have been done in proc fileDialog. However if there were more user choices to collect 
presumably we could sort them all out in proc UpdatedUserFile and proceed.

proc fileDialog should return a local $userFile, it's all about remembering the $$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to use a global variable.

```
proc fileDialog {w ent} {
    global userFile
    set types { {"All files"       *} }

    set file [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types -parent $w]

    if {[string compare $file ""]} {

        # Only update the global if the user didn't cancel
        set userFile $file

        $ent delete 0 end
        $ent insert 0 $userFile
        $ent xview end
    }

    puts "line 34: local userFile is $userFile"
}
```

The rest of your code can then read that global to get the file. The main tricky bit is that the global will change when the user accepts a file in the dialog; you handle that by setting a *write trace* on the `userFile` global variable, and update the UI when that changes. Of course, you can do the easiest version of this by using the `-textvariable` option of a `label`: that sets the trace for you behind the scenes so it always shows you the current contents of the variable:

```
pack [label .showTheUserFile -textvariable userFile]
```

You only need to set the trace directly (with `trace`) for more complex interactions:

```
trace add variable userFile write UpdatedUserFile
proc UpdatedUserFile {args} {
    # Note that we're ignoring the arguments to the callback here; we only ever apply
    # this trace to one event on one variable so we know what's going on without
    # being told explicitly

    # Here's a very simple version; for more complicated versions, see your imagination!

    global userFile
    puts "The user has selected the file $userFile"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having (and still am) is forgetting to use $ to reference a variable. This leads to bizarre errors when trying to pass parameters and can lead the inexperienced to start doing weird and wonderful things, as in the original question. Thanks for the help, I think I'd have given up altogether otherwise!

Proper version follows:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "get user specified file name"

labelframe .fileSelectorGroup -text "press the button to choose your file"

set userFileChoice "userFileChoice is bound to this field"
# note not $userFileChoice in next line
entry .fileSelectorGroup.ent -width 40 -textvariable userFileChoice
button .fileSelectorGroup.but -text "Kindly press this button and choose a file.\nNot only will I write the file name\nin the the field to the left, I'll make\nit appear in the console."\
 -command "getUserFileAndProceed .fileSelectorGroup .fileSelectorGroup.ent"

pack .fileSelectorGroup.ent -side left -padx 10 -expand yes -fill x
pack .fileSelectorGroup.but -side left -padx 10 -pady 3
pack .fileSelectorGroup -fill x -padx 2c -pady 3
focus .fileSelectorGroup.ent

proc getUserFileAndProceed {w ent} {
    set userChoice [fileDialog $w $ent]
    puts "line 21: userChoice is $userChoice"
    puts "have a nice day"
}

proc fileDialog {w ent} {
    set types { {"All files"       *} }

    set userFile [tk_getOpenFile -multiple false -filetypes $types -parent $w -typevariable "All files"]

    if {[string compare $userFile ""]} {
        $ent delete 0 end
        $ent insert 0 $userFile
        $ent xview end
    }

    return $userFile
}
```